# How to order united request by date?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I select 'title' from one table and order by 'date'. I select 'title' from other table and order by 'date'(two columns with same name in two tables). Then I unite them like this.

```
(SELECT title FROM books WHERE id = :id ORDER BY date DESC) UNION ALL (SELECT title FROM movies WHERE id = :id ORDER BY date DESC);
```

How can I oder them all together by date?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not select `date`, you can't; if you add `date` to the selects, you can just remove the parenthesis, and the first `ORDER BY` clause. Without parenthesis, MySQL applies ORDER BY to the entire UNION

Answer (score 0):

For ordering a column you must have in select like the sample below

```
SELECT title, `date` FROM books WHERE id = :id
UNION ALL 
SELECT title, `date` FROM movies WHERE id = :id 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

You can sort using order by only columns present in select ..so you need date .. and you can only union table with the same column ( number, type) so the date is in both the select .. and in union the order is needed only at the end of the query

Comment: I can't fully understand what does it mean. Will this unite 'date' from both tables or what?

Comment: I have update the answer with some brief explanation